# I want to calculate the probability of each element occurring in a vector

Tags: image, probability, matlab-cvst

I have tried it using arrayfun() as follows as answered on stackoverflow:

```
prob_y = arrayfun(@(x)length(find(y==x)), unique(y)) / length(y)
```

But the problem with this is that I have to find the occurrences of 40 different  values in a vector, so I'll have to use this arrayfun() for 40 times and it runs faster for the first value, but when it goes for the 2nd value it takes hell lot of time and my vector size is also huge. Can someone please suggest me some alternative for this so that it can save my time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hist` and `unique` together to do this efficiently.

```
[a, b] = hist(y, unique(y));
a = a/length(y);
```